# Drag down and change value of formula

Tags: excel, drag, excel-formula

I have this formula:

**=IF(INDIRECT("summary!a2")="","",INDIRECT("summary!a2"))**

.. this will retrieve the value of the a2 cell in the summary sheet.

What i want to know is what can i do on this formula to allow the value a2 to change to a3/a4/a5 etc.. when dragged down the sheet .

Can anyone give me a hint here?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a regular formula?

Comment: @TimWilliams this is for cases when rows on 'summary' sheet are deleted, but I need to always refer to the top, i.e. A2 value - I use such indirect constructions on my own. Macro removes rows, but I always get A2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `=IF(INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(A2))="","",INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(A2)))` - applicable for drag down)

Comment: Thanks Peter, that works fine when dragged down.

However ( and this is weird), if i drag the cell to the right  it does not update


for e.g 
=IF(INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(A2))="","",INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(A2)))

=IF(INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(B2))="","",INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(B2)))

=IF(INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(c2))="","",INDIRECT("summary!a"&ROW(c2)))

and so on..

Both retrieve the same value of A2..

What could it be?

Comment: The issue is not for dragging to the right, it's that the value is not correct . 

e.g.
Summary sheet
A1- Dog
B1 - Cat
C1 - Bird

If i use the code above i always get the value of A1 (dog) and even though the cell reference is ok, it does not update

Comment: @user2034202 for drag down you should use my answer, for drag to the right - this one: `=IF(INDIRECT("summary!a"&COLUMN(B1))="","",INDIRECT("summary!a"&COLUMN(B1)))`. This is because how Excel changes references: if you drag any formula with A2 *DOWN* - Excel cycles number, since rows are changing. When drag to the right - B1 will change to C1 and so on, i.e. COLUMN changes. Try both, but remember each formula is ok for the respective drag direction.

Comment: @user2034202 Or simply: ROW(A2), ROW(B2) and ROW(C2) will all return 2, since for all these cells row is 2.

Comment: Sorry not sure if im explaining myself right, please check this link
http://s3.postimage.org/8vb6ezpir/excel.png 

The problem i have is that the cells are not retrieving the value they are supposed too ..

Only the first cell shows the correct value..

Comment: @user2034202 to achieve what you want just put `=IF(INDIRECT("sheet1!a"&COLUMN(B1))="","",INDIRECT("sheet1!a"&COLUMN(B1)))` to A1 of Sheet2 and drag to the right. You'll see all is fine. Or shall I share my sample?)

Comment: can you please? 

My intention is just to get the respective values on the cell A1-B1-C1 etc. and then drag everything down the sheet. so i can have a2-b2-d2 -> a3-b3-d3 etc

Comment: @user2034202 did you mean a2-b2-**c**2?

Comment: I'm looking to mirror sheet Summary to Sheet Summary1.
I want Summary1 to be a perfect clone (updating automatically) of the Summary sheet.

The way i found (maybe not the best) was this one, using the indirect formula.

If you see on my screenshot, i want that on sheet 2 the cell b2 and c3 give me the same values i'm pulling them from sheet1, so.. dog-cat-bird. From then i want to select them and drag down to move to the bottom cells

Comment: @user2034202 Check my sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6eervugh86rgsk/DragINDIRECT.xlsx The clue is that you may NOT use the same INDIRECT formula for dragging in BOTH directions: `INDIRECT("sheet1!a"` will ALWAYS refer to Sheet1 column **A**, only row number may change regardless of how it is calculated. Therefore you need a new formula for **every** new column for the 1st row, i.e. `INDIRECT("sheet1!b"`, `INDIRECT("sheet1!c"` and so on. Hope with the help of my sample you now got the idea)

Comment: @user2034202 if what you really want is sheets mirroring - start a new question, I think I have a solution for that, but it's a bit different. Here you asked for `Drag down and change value of formula` specifying a2-a3-a4-... - and my answer works fine for this.

Comment: This does the purpose of mirroring as well. just tried it now and works perfectly. Thanks for the sample, i realized where was my mistake

Comment: @user2034202 thisi is what you want, and with just ONE simple formula: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tokwawrbzpqtefd/SheetMirroring.xlsx

Comment: Peter, i had a few problems with the outcome after..i posted another question on a separate thread, if you could help me it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

If you use CELL function you can also drag down and across, e.g.

`=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&CELL("address",A1))`